# How to report the behavior of the user of the program in a scenario?

Tags: modal-verbs

Suppose I want to report the behavior of a user of my program in the comment of code. in this case, the user may be changing his opinion of choosing an action based on something and this behavior effects on something else. Is the following sentence right?

> The user might change the 'Accounting Year name' and 'date period' at the end of the Opening process.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is grammatically correct, but "The user might change.." sounds like you are talking about something that the user might decide to do at some time in the future.

If the user has already decided to change something, and at this stage in the code you are simply dealing with the consequences of the change, it would be better to say

> The user might have changed the 'Accounting Year name' and 'date period' at the end of the Opening process.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the user is permitted to make the change at that point, then the correct word is "may", as in "may I open the door? - Yes, you  may".

That question could have been worded "Might I open the door?" which is rather old-fashioned but supposed to be even more polite. But the answer would always be "You may" and not "You might".